# How to match all items in a list using regex

Tags: regex, python-2.7

Am trying to use regex to perform a certain code.In an example below, my intention is to get all items in name to match if found in name3 and get printed out. The issue is that only the first item in the string that matches is printed out.

```
import re

def foo():    
    for counter, option in enumerate(keywords):        
        try:            
            name = 'can one and three be odd numbers'
            name2 = name[:]
            name3 = ['one','two','three', 'four',]            
            regex1one = re.compile(r'\b(?:%s)\b'%'|'.join(name3))
            regex11one = re.compile(r'\b(?:%s)\b'%'|'.join(keywords))            
            name4 = regex1one.search(name).group()
            print name4
            break
        except:
            break

keywords = ['be','are','is',]

foo()
```

Comment: If you plan to get multiple matches, use `re.findall` or `re.finditer`. And your string does contain 1 `one` to be matched. There is no `two`, `three`, nor `four`

Comment: in this example code, it will only print ['one'].I want ['one','three']. How will findall() do this? I tried with findall() before asking but still havent had an answer

Comment: You spelled three wrong in name, findall should work.

Comment: without break, still doesn't print both items

Comment: Closing for typo. Fix the spelling of "three" in `name` and use `findall` , then it works. Also, remove the useless loop.

Comment: It is really a typo. Closing.

Comment: @tobias_k, there is nothing useless in my code. This is a snippet from a code am trying to work on here.

Comment: As it stands, the `for` loop _is_ useless, because you do not use the `counter` and `option` variables and break after the first iteration. Your code behaves _exactly the same_ without the loop. The unused `name2` is useless, too, and the catch-and-hide-all-errors `try/except` is not only useless but harmfull.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to tobias_k, i removed all the useless stuff. Here it is:

import re

```
def foo():
    name = 'can one and three be odd numbers'    
    name3 = ['one','two','three', 'four',]            
    regex1one = re.compile(r'\b(?:%s)\b'%'|'.join(name3))
    regex11one = re.compile(r'\b(?:%s)\b'%'|'.join(keywords))
    name4 = re.findall(regex1one, name)
    print name4
keywords = ['be','are','is',]

foo()
```